# Some misunderstandings with the formal developments of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am currently reading Amann/Escher's *Analysis I* and am struggling to develop their formal development of the isomorphism between polynomials (as a subset of the set of formal power series) and polynomial functions. I have included their discussion here, and have some questions which pertain to it:
[image]

Now I want to emphasize at the outset that the authors have defined (rather abstractly, as is their custom) things as follows. The **formal power series ring over $R$** was defined as the function space $R^\mathbb{N}$ along with the usual (for formal power series) operations of addition and Cauchy multiplication, and called $R[\![X]\!]$. The **subring of polynomials** was then defined as that subset of $R[\![X]\!]$ wherein the set $\{n \mid p_n \neq 0 \}$ is finite, and called $R[X]$.

My confusion here is twofold:

1. I am struggling to close out the proof of Remark 8.14(b) as it pertains to multiplication. From the (Cauchy product) definition of multiplication in  $R[\![X]\!]$ (and thus in $R[X]$, by restriction), we have that $(pq)_n = \sum_{j=0}^n p_jq_{n-j}$, so that by the definition of the value of $pq$ at $x \in R$ we have
   $$(pq)(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\deg (pq)}\left(\sum_{j=0}^n p_jq_{n-j}\right)x^n.$$
   However, I am struggling to see how I can massage this into the requisite
   $$p(x)q(x) = \left(\sum_{j=0}^{\deg (p)}p_jx^j\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\deg (q)}q_ix^i\right)$$
   form. Any hints here would be greatly appreciated. As these are just algebraic preliminaries to an analysis text, the authors are rather brief.
2. I don't follow (or even agree with?) their proof of Remark 8.14(c). In particular, why are they saying that $R[X] = R^\mathbb{N}$ when, as far as I can tell, it is in fact that $R[\![X]\!] = R^\mathbb{N}$, with $R[X] \subset R[\![X]\!]$ a proper subset thereof. I think I can still rescue the proof by showing that $R[X]$ is infinite, but (a) it's not clear why it should be uncountably so (the fact that $R[\![X]\!] = R^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable I agree with, but it's not clear why this subset thereof should be?) and (b) I don't think uncountability matters here -- if we have that $R[X]$ infinite then certainly it won't inject into the finite set $R^R$.

Comment: You're right, that $R[X] = R^{\mathbb{N}}$ bit is just a mistake. You only need to show that $R[X]$ is infinite. It is not necessarily uncountably infinite, and in fact it is countably infinite if $R$ is at most countably infinite. As for your first question, just expand it out and then collect like terms carefully.

Comment: Interesting. So $R[\![X]\!]$ is uncountably infinite no matter what, but $R[X]$ is uncountably infinite iff $R$ is uncountably infinite? Regarding a proof that $R[X]$ itself is infinite, would you argue by contradiction and say something like "if $R[X]$ were finite, then (since that set is finite) we could take the maximum degree of a polynomial in that set, call it $x$, but that that contradicts that that the polynomial with $p_{x+1} = 1$ and the rest 0 is in $R[X]$ and has degree $x+1$"? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: For your first question, isn't this quite literally how the Cauchy product is defined? This of course coincides with multiplication in $R$ due to distributivity.

Comment: I will see if I can work out the first question and, if not, hopefully it's OK to come back and bother you. Thanks so much for your help as always!

Comment: @Ennar My text has defined the Cauchy product on $R[X]$, but here I am tasked with showing that that results in the usual Cauchy product form when I multiply out "values of two different polynomials at the same $x \in R$". Not sure if I'm being clear enough to make any sense, apologies if not!

Comment: The point I want to make is that Cauchy product works for polynomial functions that you are used to. It's just distributivity plus $x^i\cdot x^j = x^{i+j}$. For example, $(x^2+2x+3)(x^2+x+1)$, the only way to get $x^4$ is through $x^2\cdot x^2$, to get $x^3$ it's $x^2\cdot x + 2x\cdot x^2$, to get $x^2$ it's $x^2\cdot 1+2x\cdot x + 3\cdot x^2$ etc.

Comment: @EE18: no, it's completely unnecessary to argue by contradiction here. You can prove directly that $R[X]$ is infinite by exhibiting an injection from any infinite set, for example $\mathbb{N} \ni n \mapsto X^n \in R[X]$ which works over any ring.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you! Does the answer I've posted below generally summarize our agreed-upon conclusions here?

Comment: @EE18: your arguments are correct but I think you're making things too hard for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Question (1):

Following the discussion with Qiaochu Yuan and Ennar, I believe this can be proved by induction on the degree of one of the two polynomials.

Question (2):

We argue by contradiction. Suppose $R[X]$ were finite, and define the set of degrees of polynomials in $R[X]$, call it $D$. This set is finite since clearly $R[X]$ surjects thereon and $R[X]$ is finite. Since $D$ is finite, and since finite subsets of $\Bbb N \cup \{-\infty\}$ always have a maximum and minimum, we can define the maximum degree of a polynomial in that set, call it $x$. But that contradicts that the polynomial with $p_{x+1} = 0$ and the rest of its $p_j = 0$ is in $R[X]$, so that $x+1 \in D$ with $x+1 > x$.

Alternatively, as suggested by Qiaochu, we argue as follows. Define the map $\psi: \mathbb{N} \ni n \mapsto X^n \in R[X]$ which has $\mathbb{N}$ inject into $R[X]$: it is an injection, for if $m \neq n$ then $X^m \neq X^n$ (the functions $X^m,X^n$ take on the value 1 at $n,m$). Thus $R[X]$ must be infinite (if an infinite set injects into another set, then that latter set is infinite).